# How to connect Unity Mobile App to Azure SQL Database?

Tags: c#, database, azure, unity-game-engine, mobile

im developing an app in Unity for Android and iOS.

The app will prompt the user to fill out a survey on the first use, I need the data from that survey to be stored in a database for analytics and I decided it would be Azure.

What Azure services will I need to implement this functionality? I need it to be as little and economical as possible as they are the only data I will store and the app is small.

And from the Azure services needed, how do you implement that functionality? Any tutorials for beginners?

I also have basic knowledge of Azure.

Thank you very much! I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a POST method.

Create a PHP file to connect to your database and then use your code to send the data.

example C#:

```
public void CreateUser(string username, string firstName, string lastName, string email, string phoneNumber)
    {
            WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
            form.AddField("userNamePost", username);
            form.AddField("firstNamePost", firstName);
            form.AddField("lastNamePost", lastName);
            form.AddField("phoneNumberPost", phoneNumber);
            form.AddField("emailPost", email);
            WWW www = new WWW("URL of the PHP file", form);
    }
```

example PHP:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$server_username = "root";
$server_password = "";
$dbName = "databaseName";

$userName = $_POST['userNamePost'];
$firstName = $_POST['firstNamePost'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastNamePost'];
$phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumberPost'];
$emailAddress = $_POST['emailPost'];

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $server_username, $server_password, $dbName);

if(!$conn)
{
    die("Connection Failed" .mysqli_connect_error());
}
else
{
    echo "Connected";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (all field names) VALUES ('".$userName."','".$firstName."','".$lastName."','".$phoneNumber."','".$emailAddress."')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
```